# Angularjs : ng-enter animation is only triggered once

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

The entering animation is triggered only the first time.

I am using Angularjs 1.2.22

Given this CSS :

```
.ng-enter {
    animation: bounceInUp 2s;
}

.ng-leave {
    animation: bounceOutUp 2s;
}
```

And this route :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/horodateur/currentuser', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/horodateur/currentuser.html',
            controller: 'CurrentUserController'
        }).

        when('/horodateur/keypad', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/horodateur/keypad.html',
              controller: 'KeypadController'
        }).

        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/horodateur/currentuser'
        });
  }]);
```

The **first time** the partial view is shown, **I can see the entering animation.**

A button on that first partial view gives back control to it's controller to load another view :

```
app.controller('CurrentUserController', 
    function ($scope, $location) {
        $scope.showKeypad = function () {
            $location.path('/horodateur/keypad');
        }
    });
```

At this point, **I can see the leaving animation** of the first partial view.

Then, the second partial view is rendered, **but this time, no entering animation.**

If I hit the browser's back button to return to the first partial view, I can still see the leaving animation, but I cannot see the entering animation of the other partial view.

It must be something I don't understand with partial views loading or rendering ...

Anybody knows what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I just don't understand why ...

To see the entering animation after the leaving animation of the previous view, I had to augment the `animation-duration` of the entering animation.

Both at 500ms just don't work. I had to keep the leaving animation at a lower duration (500 ms) but augment the entering animation to 1500ms or higher to be able to see it.